# python-docx How to get content/body of a section

Tags: python, file, docx, python-docx

I am using Word's sections term to be able for each page to have different header, where I mark page with some markup like `{page1}`.

Using `python-docx` I get sections by:

```
doc = Document(my_file)`
doc_sections = doc.sections
doc_page_one = doc_sections[0]
```

I am able to get header and footer of each page and their texts:

`doc_page_one.header.paragraphs[0].text`

But I don't see the actual page content/body or shapes, while debugging I was not able to find where do they live.

Does `python-docx` have this possibility?

Answer (score 2):

At present, `python-docx` does not have API support for getting what I would imagine would be the "block-items" (paragraphs + tables) that are "contained" in a certain section.

You would have to navigate the underlying XML if you wanted it bad enough, probably starting at `document._body._body.xml`. You could get an idea what that looks like with:

```
print(document._body._body.xml)
```

Basically you'd be looking for `w:sectPr` elements, each of which *ends* a section. There is some more detail on the XML schema involved in the `python-docx` analysis page here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/sections.html